# From string with locale to date on iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, locale, string-formatting

I trying to find a way to convert a string into a date with a given locale identifier.
I have for example an italian date (locale: it_IT) I want to convert into a valid date object.

```
NSDate *GLDateWithString(NSString *string, NSString *localeIdentifier) {
    [NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:localeIdentifier];
    [formatter setLocale:locale];
    [locale release];

    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:string];
    [formatter release];

    return date;
}
```

this code does not work, the date is nil.
I can't figure out how I should use the locale setting for my purpose.

Comment: Give an example string you're using.

Comment: I posted the solution and an example here, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use getObjectValue:forString:range:error: method of NSDateFormatter and set the correct date and time style ad follow:

```
- (NSDate *)dateWithString:(NSString *)string locale:(NSString *)localeIdentifier {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:localeIdentifier];
    [formatter setLocale:locale];
    [locale release];

    NSDate *date = nil;
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [string length]);
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL converted = NO;
    converted = [formatter getObjectValue:&date forString:string range:&range error:&error];
    [formatter release];

    return converted? date : nil;
}
```

example:

```
NSString *italianDate = @"30/10/2010";
NSString *italianLocale = @"it_IT";

NSDate *date = [myCustomFormatter dateWithString:italianDate locale:italianLocale];
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, always good to have a working sample. Welcome as a teacher at stackoverflow.com :-)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with German formats as well sometime ago and solved the problem by supplying my own formatting string:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MMM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

Then:

```
[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"01.Dez.2010 15:03:00"];
```

will get a correct NSDate.

Comment: Of course this works, but NSDateFormatter is supposed to choose the correct date format for me since I set the locale identifier. This is what I thought, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I agree. Most often there is just a little thing wrong with your input. You can try it out with NSDateFormatter's getObjectValue:forString:range:error: method. Maybe returned NSError provides you a reasonable explanation why it failed.

Comment: thank you kay, with getObjectValue:... works like a charm! I also had to set correct date/time style. I posted the full solution here