# NSDate time converting from 12hr to 24 hr format

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

hi i have problem while converting Date Formats... 
the date time is in the Format 12 hour Format like **12/9/2010 4:00:00 PM**
 (Month/date/year Hour:Min:sec Pm)
i need to Convert it into 24 hour format like **12/9/2010 16:00:00**
Can any one Help me please....
Thx in advance

Comment: Is it in a `NSString` or is originating as a `NSDate`?

Answer (score 6):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateformatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm a";
NSDate *date = [dateformatter dateFromString:departTime];
dateformatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
NSString *time24 = [dateformatter stringFromDate:date];
departTimelbl.text=time24;
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply do This to get 24 hour time format (In Swift 2)

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm a"  //(hh:mm a----> for 12 hour format)
let timeString = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
print(timeString)
```

UPDATE: Swift 3 version

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm a"  //(hh:mm a----> for 12 hour format)
let timeString = formatter.string(from: Date())
print(timeString)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a `NSDateFormatter`.  I encourage you to read the class reference as linked by `Kay`.

Here's how you'd do it.  I'm assuming the date is originating as a `NSString`.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString:yourNSString]; 
NSString *myNewDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];
[formatter release];
[myDate release];
```

Comment: Just saw my own answer and I'm embarrassed to say, "don't release `myDate`".  I made this when I was still new to programming.  =)

Answer (score 2):

Use these functions,this will change the date string from 12 to 24 hr formate and 24 to 12hr formate.

```
-(NSString *)changeformate_string24hr:(NSString *)date
{

    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];

    NSDate* wakeTime = [df dateFromString:date];

    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];


    return [df stringFromDate:wakeTime];

}

-(NSString *)changeformate_string12hr:(NSString *)date
{

    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate* wakeTime = [df dateFromString:date];


    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];


    return [df stringFromDate:wakeTime];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"15:15"];

dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm a";
NSString *pmamDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at NSDateFormatter [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the [data formatting guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000029i). There you will find more especially the method dateFromString and stringFromDate are interesting for you. There is another question dealing with similar problem [From string with locale to date on iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334871/from-string-with-locale-to-date-on-iphone-sdk/4335813#4335813) where you can find some sample code when you want to set a special formatting template string.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Swift

   ```
   var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
   var date: Date? = dateFormatter.date(from: "12/9/2010 4:00:00 PM")
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
   var convertedString: String? = nil
   if let aDate = date {
       convertedString = dateFormatter.string(from: aDate)
   }
   ```
2. In Objective C

   ```
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a";
   NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"12/9/2010 4:00:00 PM"];
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
   NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
   ```