# Objective C - Converting time from 12 to 24 format issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm converting the time from 12 to 24 format using the below code and its working fine, but the result is less than the actual time by 3 hours!
i.e : if the time is "12:40 pm", I am getting "09:40" after converting to 24 format.

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];    
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSDate* newDate = [df dateFromString:strDate4Convert];    
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];    
NSString *newTimeStr = [df stringFromDate:newDate];
```

Thanks in advance;

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395832/nsdate-time-converting-from-12hr-to-24-hr-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set timeZone to `UTC` or your `localTimeZone` instead of `systemTimeZone`.

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
//Or [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSDate* newDate = [df dateFromString:@"12/02/2016 12:40 pm"];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *newTimeStr = [df stringFromDate:newDate];
```

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

yes, use localtimezone

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSDate* newDate = [df dateFromString:@"08/30/2016 12:40 am"]; // @"08/30/2016 12:40 pm"
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *newTimeStr = [df stringFromDate:newDate];
```

Output:

Printing description of newTimeStr:
08/30/2016 00:40:00

Printing description of newTimeStr:
08/30/2016 12:40:00